# Parse GeoJson and put MultiLineString on Android Map

Tags: android, dictionary, geojson, multilinestring

I need to draw on Android Map , a GeoJson MultiLineString coordinates that I am getting from a WebService. Actually I know how to work with JSON , get a Latitud and Longitude and draw this on Map, but I don't know how to do it with GeoJson. I watched a video that explain how to manage Points on GeoJson, but I dont know how to manage a MultiLineString.
I hope you can help me with some Android example.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google maps for android, then check out the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/).

[Specifically for geojson](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/geojson)
It is as simple as:

```
GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(getMap(), geoJsonData);
layer.addLayer();
```

However, I have found I needed to use:

```
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

in my Fragment...